# Child class properties cannot be set from Parent class's constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I´m using this exact code in nextjs and it always log

```
class A { // A: Model
    constructor(source){
        Object.keys(source)
        .forEach(key => {
            if(!this[key]){
                this[key] = source[key];
            }
        });
    }
}

class B extends A{ // B: User
    first_name: string;
}

let v = new B({first_name: "nof"});
console.log(v)
// B { first_name: undefined }
```

But when using in non nextjs project it just work and shows both n1, and m2
I belive this is related to some configurations on nextjs; any idea on how to achieve that without declarign a constructor in B class ?

---

This is the original example, kept here as a references for the answers below:

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        this.init()
    }
    init(){
        this["n1"] = "nof";
        this["n2"] = "nof";
    }
}

class B extends A{
    n1: string;
}

let v = new B();
console.log(v)
// B { n1: undefined, n2: 'foo' }
```

Comment: Is `e` in `Object.keys(e)` (and later) meant to be `source`?

Comment: My apologies
Yes e is meant to be source

Comment: What type do you have on `source`?

Comment: just a javascript object 
I usually pass the object returned by a SQL query builder result (knex in my case)

Comment: "just a javascript object" isn't a type name. Do you mean `object`? `{}`? Something else?

Comment: The code as shown produces multiple type errors in TypeScript's playground with default settings: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oHplwFzQLIHsAmApiAFDRnTA4B2EALgE4CuwtO9AFBDo-cAQJQJS5EQHkARgCsCLAHQBrAgE8InbrwHCRZWQDM2AUTDAAFu0VLoAXgB8iLdpEBLXewCEtE04gBtCwF1BB0dHT28-ZX9raC4ePgilfwBuYJCAX1SyNP4UkQyM4lBIGAAhaAIAD1oCKjwYWCRUaBLMAFUIAnoHXSd6OgB9KjAAWwJMOnonKgBzFIKQAlpoADdoqgIAd2b2BB6+2kGRsegAIiocXRPslMoaHAXZEBxp9mX+YiaypD2BodHMRi1Ag9dZ4aBpIA Please provide code that compiles without errors unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The result is as expected. When constructing a new object B it first constructs A so then both n1 and n2 are set to 'nof'. Then B is constructed and overwrites n1 with an unset(always undefined) variable so n1 = undefined and n2 should still be 'nof'.

Comment: This answer suggests that there are separate objects created by `new B`, one that's an `A` object and one that's a `B` object. That's incorrect. There is only **one** object created, not two. The reason for the behavior the OP sees is that `n1` is *redefined* by `B`'s constructor; more in the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields).

Comment: I wanted to keep the answer as simple as possible hence the wording 'new object' is only used once. But you are right that it is not so clear that B and A are constructed on the same place in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that behavior because apparently you now have [`useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields) enabled, where before you didn't have it enabled. From that link:

> Use Define For Class Fields - `useDefineForClassFields`
>
> This flag is used as part of migrating to the upcoming standard version of class fields. TypeScript introduced class fields many years before it was ratified in TC39. The latest version of the upcoming specification has a different runtime behavior to TypeScript’s implementation but the same syntax.
>
> This flag switches to the upcoming ECMA runtime behavior.
>
> You can read more about the transition in the 3.7 release notes.

What's happening is that after `A`'s constructor has finished running, `B`'s (implicit) constructor *redefines* the property (replacing the one `A` defined), losing the value `A` created in the process. As noted in the quote above, JavaScript does the same thing:

```js
class A { // A: Model
    constructor(source){
        Object.keys(source)
        .forEach(key => {
            if(!this[key]){
                this[key] = source[key];
            }
        });
    }
}

class B extends A{ // B: User
    first_name/*: string*/;
}

let v = new B({first_name: "nof"});
console.log(v)
// B { first_name: undefined }
```

You could turn that setting off to get the output you want from that code; [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oHplwFzQLIHsAmApiAFDRnTA4B2EALgE4CuwtO9AFBDo-cAQJQJS5EQHkARgCsCLAHQBrAgE8InbrwHCRZWQDM2AUTDAAFu0VLoAXgB8iLdpEBLXewCEtE04gBtCwF1BB0dHT28-ZX9raC4ePgilfwBuYJCAX1SyNP4UkQyM4lBIGAAhaAIAD1oCKjwYWCRUaBLMAFUIAnoHXSd6OgB9KjAAWwJMOnonKgBzFIKQAlpoADdoqgIAd2b2BB6+2kGRsegAIiocXRPslMoaHAXZEBxp9mX+YiaypD2BodHMM4XE7QNJAA) *(I haven't tried to fix the other type errors in that)*. **But I strongly recommend you update the code instead.** Just from a design perspective, `A` shouldn't be initializing properties that it doesn't define. Moreover, it's not typesafe to dump all of the properties of an object you receive into the instance you're initializing.

I would suggest simply writing the constructors and having them copy the data they're supposed to copy. Amongst other things, that prevents the instances from getting properties from `source` that don't exist on them as in this JavaScript example ([TypeScript version here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oHplwFzQLIHsAmApiAFDRnTA4B2EALgE4CuwtO9AFBDo-cAQJQJS5EQHkARgCsCLAHQBrAgE8InbrwHCRZWQDM2AUTDAAFu0VLoAXgB8iLdpEBLXewCEtE04gBtCwF1BB0dHT28-ZX9raC4ePgilfwBuYJCAX1SyNP4UkQyM4lBIGAAhaAIAD1oCKjwYWCRUaBLMAFUIAnoHXSd6OgB9KjAAWwJMOnonKgBzFIKQAlpoADdoqgIAd2b2BB6+2kGRsegAIiocXROAGhiTbhA8ADkcWhKCAAlO45P3p2hPL5uE7ZFKUGg4BayEA4absZY5YhNMpIPYDIajTBnC7XW73J4vN6fejfX7-EyAk7QDJNEK02kAPUZTOZLNZbKAA) *[again, I haven't tried to fix other type errors there]*):

```js
class A { // A: Model
    constructor(source){
        Object.keys(source)
        .forEach(key => {
            if(!this[key]){
                this[key] = source[key];
            }
        });
    }
}

class B extends A{ // B: User
    first_name;
}

let v = new B({first_name: "nof", shouldNotBeHere: "Hi there!"});
console.log(v);
// B { first_name: "nof", shouldNotBeHere: "Hi there!" }
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But again, if you want to have `A` do that blind copy, you can make the compiler error (but not the problem) go away by turning off the flag.

Comment: The first playground link above was broken. I've fixed it now. For some reason, even when the playground's config had the flag turned off, it was including `useDefineForClassFields=true` in the URL. I eventually had to manually fix the URL, but it works now.

Comment: Hi T.J. Crowder
I updated the code to reflect my use case exactly 
A: is a model
B: is the object class (eg: User)
I usually pass the source object then the class loop over it and set each property
I belive this is kind of fine design

Comment: @naoufalbardouni - Due respect, but I disagree. If you want type-safe code, you have to write type-safe code, just using TypeScript isn't sufficient. Looping through all the properties on an object you receive and dumping them into another object like that bypasses type checking.

Comment: You are totally right 
I'm not really looking for a type safe code in this project / i just want something to work with and still use typescript to type classes because i'm using this package to generate Grapqhl from Typescript (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bardouni/graphqly)
I wll update my code to manually set each property
Thank you

Comment: @naoufalbardouni - Well, in the short term (if that change is big and need scheduling relative to other work), you could change that setting in tsconfig.json in the meantime. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to explicitly declare the type of "n1" property in class B by adding a type declaration:

`n1!: string;`

The "!" symbol after the property name is used to declare a non-null property, which ensures that "n1" will always have a value.